# RadEditor is not working in IE11

Tags: .net, telerik

I am working on `Telerik RadEditor` control but it is not working in `IE11` although it is working fine in `IE8`. 
Below tag, I am using to work with `IE9` and `IE10` and It works

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

But, When I use `IE11` then RadEditor is not showing in proper format.

```
Namespace="Telerik.WebControls" Assembly="RadEditor.Net2"
```

Can someone tell me, what is the problem with `IE11`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on the built-in browser emulation because the browser changes and there are problems.
You are using a very very old version of RadEditor that was obsolete in 2009, years before the appearance of Internet Explorer 11. In order to fix the problem you have to upgrade to RadEditor for ASP.NET AJAX (Telerik.Web.UI.dll) which offers full and official support for IE11.

You can find upgrade instructions in the following article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-migration-from-radeditor-classic-to-radeditor-prometheus.html.